# How to Mock MVC4 application when UI testing with Watin?

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, watin, gui-testing

What Im trying to achieve is to write UI tests for my MVC4 web application using Watin. Now I create a Browser object and open on URL localhost:xxxxx.

Problem is that the code running on localhost:xxxx using IIS Express is using production code which I dont want to be doing during test. In test I want for instance my IAuth and IDataProvider implementations to behave differently.

How do you UI test on a mocked instance of your application?

Ideas? :)

Comment: Deploy with a different Dependency Injection container configuration?

Comment: But then I'd ned to remember to deploy with this configuration each time I want to run test. I was hoping to avoid this. But I guess, if there is no other way I have to do it like that :)

Comment: You could use WebDeploy with a specific Publish Profile, that would make it easy to deploy the correct code.

Comment: My final solution was to create a bat file that I run 1 time before my UI tests which reset database to a given state and run msbuild command with DeployOnBuild. Works like a charm :) Thanks for your input guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to make a bat file which runs a msbuild command which deploy to my local IIS. This works like a charm.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe C:\Source\...\ProjectName.csproj       /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile="UnitTest" /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:OutputPath="C:\inetpub\web" /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0
```